# Form inputs and button do not perfectly align

Tags: html, css, forms, button, alignment

I have a sign up form which i want to center in the middle. However, my input fields and button do not perfectly align. They do have the same size. The button is 5px wider however i also tried this with exact the same widths and the problem still occurs. Could somebody please explain to me why this happens? I also wonder why the submit button is always smaller in width even when it does have the same value? The website can be found at www.http://public-journalism.com/pages/sign_up.php

This is my html code:

```
<div id="pjsignup_container">
    <form name="signup" method="post" action='/scripts/loginscript.php'>
        Sign up
        <br>
        <input placeholder="Username" type='text' name='username' id='username'  maxlength="50" />
        <br>
        <input placeholder="Email" type='text' name='email' id='email'  maxlength="50" />
        <br>
        <input placeholder="Re-enter email" type='text' name='email' id='email'  maxlength="50" />
        <br>
        <input placeholder="Password" type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />
        <br>
        <input placeholder="Re-enter password" type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />
        <br>
        <input type='submit' id="public_journalism_button" name='signup' value='Sign me up!'/>
        <p>By signing up, you agree to our <a href="#">terms of use</a>, <a href="#">privacy policy</a>, <a href="#">and cookie policy</a>.</p>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is my css code:

```
#pjsignup_container {
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}

#pjsignup_container input {
    width: 220px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

#pjsignup_container input[type=submit] {
    width: 225px;
    height: 30px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #0072C6;          
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <center>
    <div id="pjsignup_container">
        <form name="signup" method="post" action='/scripts/loginscript.php'>
            Sign up
            <br>
            <input placeholder="Username" type='text' name='username' id='username'  maxlength="50" />
            <br>
            <input placeholder="Email" type='text' name='email' id='email'  maxlength="50" />
            <br>
            <input placeholder="Re-enter email" type='text' name='email' id='email'  maxlength="50" />
            <br>
            <input placeholder="Password" type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />
            <br>
            <input placeholder="Re-enter password" type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />
            <br>
            <input type='submit' id="public_journalism_button" name='signup' value='Sign me up!'/>
            <p>By signing up, you agree to our <a href="#">terms of use</a>, <a href="#">privacy policy</a>, <a href="#">and cookie policy</a>.</p>
        </form>
    </div>
    </center>
```

here i use only center tag to align it in middle

Answer (score 0):

the br seem to be causing the misalignment. Removing them in the inspector aligned the inputs properly. Give your inputs margin: 10px auto 0; instead of margin-top: 10px;
 Also, your input seems to be box-sizing:border-box; by it's behavior, and the inputs seem to be content-box. Size your submit to width 229px to match the other inputs, or otherwise.

Comment: Hello vlad, some part of your answer seems to be missing. You are referring to something but i can not see it. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @user2756101 fixed that. Apparently SO doesn't escape the br tag

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `width` and `margin` at wrapper element (`#pjsignup_container` ).

code example

```
#pjsignup_container {
    width: 220px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}
```

Because

```
margin: 0 auto; 
/* is equal to(=) */ 
margin: 0 calc(50% - width/2);
```

Example

```
#eg {
 width: 500px;
 margin: 0 auto; /* or */ margin: 0 calc(50% - 500px/2);
}
```

Nice a have day. Good Luck